# How to profile a Windows Service (an easy way)?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I need to profile a Windows Service made in C Sharp, I would like to know if there is any tools within Windows 7 Professional which would allow it. Or some Free Application easy to setup.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Debug Diag: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&safe=active&sclient=psy-ab&q=How+to+profile+a+.Net+service&oq=How+to+profile+a+.Net+service&gs_l=hp.3..33i29l2.12719.18579.2.18829.7.7.0.0.0.2.219.1172.0j4j3.7.0...0.0...1c.1.IERGb-JOaL8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=c3f8c9d111b3741a&biw=1280&bih=841

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perfview: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567, ETW-based.

Comment: PerfView works great, and it is very simple to install and use thanks!

Comment: Updated github link (old link is obsolete): https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/blob/master/documentation/Downloading.md